# Is $r\times[0, 2 \pi)$ the preimage of the circle $f(r, \theta) = (r \cos{\theta}, r \sin{\theta})$

Tags: functions, notation, circles

If a circle with radius $r$ is given in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where $f(r, \theta) = (r \cos{\theta}, r \sin{\theta})$, shouldn't the preimage of this circle be $r\times[0, 2 \pi)$, with $r$ a fixed positive real number?  Is there better notation for this?

Comment: This is a message from $[2\pi,4\pi)$: "Why are you discriminating against me?!"

Comment: Oh, that's funny!  Thanks for very wittily correcting me!  I could modify this in the following way(?): the preimage of this circle is {$r$} $\times$ $[x - \pi, x + \pi)$, for any chosen $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

The preimage consists of *all* points mapping onto the circle, so you should not limit yourself to any particular range of values for $\theta$.  The preimage is *all* of $\{r\} \times \mathbb{R}$ (i.e., no restriction on $\theta$ at all).

Answer (score 0):

I will start with a formal discussion. Let $\varphi: X\to Y$ be any function. The preimage of a set $Y'\subseteq Y$ is the following set $$\varphi^{-1}(Y')=\{x\in X:\varphi(x)\in Y'\}$$ Now, you already know this, but I think it will clear your confusion if we dwell on that expression a little. The set $\varphi^{-1}(Y')$ is the set of *all* $x\in X$ which get mapped into $Y'$.

Now, let's look at your specific example $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$. What is the preimage of the singleton set $\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\}$? It is the set of all $(r,\phi)$ such that $\cos\phi=\cos\theta$ and $\sin\phi=\sin\theta$. Notice that there are infinitely many possibilities for $\phi$. Thus the set $f^{-1}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ is infinite. Do you see where you went wrong in your attempts now?